# How to select a property from a higher level class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to call the `price` property from the `GroceryItem` class to use in a method which is in a sub-class of `GroceryItem` called `FindCost`.

Should I be passing it from the `GroceryItem` method or the property?

```
class GroceryItem
{
    public string name;
    public double price;

    public GroceryItem(string a, double b) {
        name = a;
        price = b;
    }

    class PurchasedItem
    {
        public int quantity;

        public double FindCost() {
            return GroceryItem.price * this.quantity * 1.10;
        } 

        class FreshItem
        {
            public double weight;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not mean that if you defined nested classes then you can access the properties of up class.

Comment: Is it your requirement to make sub-classes? Cannot you make inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: I would suggested taking a brief look at the .NET Framework Guidelines on nested types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/nested-types

Comment: @DhavalR Yeah sub-classes are required.

Comment: I think you can use composite to make it. you can try my answer:) @Roscoverheij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your requirement to make sub class, please see below code.

```
class GroceryItem
{
    public string name;
    public double price;
    public PurchasedItem pItem
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public GroceryItem(string a, double b)
    {
        name = a;
        price = b;
    }

    internal class PurchasedItem
    {
        GroceryItem item;
        public PurchasedItem(GroceryItem gItem)
        {
            item = new GroceryItem(gItem.name, gItem.price);
        }

        public int quantity;
        public double FindCost()
        {
            return item.price * this.quantity * 1.10;
        }

        class FreshItem
        {
            public double weight;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can make instance of `GroceryItem` like below.

```
GroceryItem item = new GroceryItem("Name", 1.00);
item.pItem = new GroceryItem.PurchasedItem(item);
item.pItem.quantity = 10;
double cost = item.pItem.FindCost();
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your question in clear words:

> Should I be passing it from the GroceryItem method or the property?

Yes, unfortunately you have too. Just because it is a nested class, it doesn't mean that the instances of these classes have any relationship.

[Link to 'static' documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Comment: (Unlike the closely-related language Java.)

Answer (score 2):

You have couple of option to get the price from `GroceryItem` in `FindCost`

1. You can inherit the `PurchasedItem` from `GroceryItem` and in that way you can have those properties in your `FindCost` method
2. You can instantiate the `GroceyItem` class in that `FindCost` method and then read the Price property.

Let me know the outcome

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `PurchasedItem` instances on `GroceryItem` construct.then passing itself in `PurchasedItem` object construct parameter.

You could follwoing this code

```
class GroceryItem
{
    public string name;

    public double price;

    public PurchasedItem Purchased { get; private set; }

    public GroceryItem(string a, double b)
    {
        name = a;
        price = b;
        Purchased = new PurchasedItem(this);
    }
}

class PurchasedItem
{
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    private GroceryItem _groceryItem;

    public PurchasedItem(GroceryItem price)
    {
        _groceryItem = price;
    }
    public double FindCost()
    {
        return _groceryItem.price * this.quantity * 1.10;
    }

    class FreshItem
    {
        public double weight;
    }
}
```

if you want to use `GroceryItem.FindCost()` method.

You can use like this directly.

```
GroceryItem grocery = new GroceryItem("test",100);
grocery.Purchased.FindCost()
```

c# online : http://rextester.com/DQR17613